# How can I display images on a MS Access 2007+ form with a hyperlink source?

Tags: images, microsoft-access, forms

I am looking to improve the efficiency of an Access 2010 database by using a web server with images and only storing the hyperlink source in the table, i.e.

```
http://www.images.com/images/image1.jpg
```

I know that one can save images as "attachements", using a "blob" object type, but when you're dealing with thousands of images, queries are bogged down, and performance suffers.

In short, is there a relatively simple way of displaying images on Access forms with a source that is a hyperlink address (storing files locally and using filepaths is not preferable)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access displays web data only via the web browser control. You could place a web browser control on your form and use the Navigate method of the web browser control to display the image from the website.

It is not that big a deal to display locally stored images (i.e., not with a hyperlink). You might find [Stephen Lebans' ImageClass demo](http://www.lebans.com/imageclass.htm) useful. I've used much earlier versions of it (I just checked and one of my apps uses version 5!), so I can guarantee that his approach works and is easy to use.

Comment: Keep in mind that the web browser control is subject to incompatibilities depending on your version of Internet Explorer, something that is not the case with the ImageClass code. If the images are accessible via SMB networking, I'd say that the ImageClass approach is going to be much more portable from machine to machine because it's not dependent on an outside control that is frequently altered by Windows Update.

Comment: Good points - I'll see how performance turns out.

Answer (score 1):

This is from Access 2007 and it worked for me. Extract the text from the hyperlink in the query to use on the report:

```
HyperlinkPart([Picture_2],5)
```

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-access/how-to-display-a-hyperlink-to-an-image-as-a/90821989-0e86-4aae-9b3a-37cab82634ce: